# Full Error Message Not Truncated Magento 2 PHP Stack Trace Cutoff

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

Basically the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356260/magento-how-to-show-full-error-message-instead-of-truncated-one but for Magento 2

I searched for this function but didn't see it not sure where the errors are being truncated at. What file in magento 2 is generating this message and truncating the file path?

Example from compiling, I can't see what is the class file 'Getfinancing\Ge...':

```
The (real) cast has been removed, use (float) instead#0 /srv/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/srv/public_htm...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Getfinancing\\Ge...')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35391

More specifically if you want to fix it in your Magento 2 you can change the file bin/magento with the change shown here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/fd7e45e945796afcb39ef96c57121f494d651754#diff-507a115131c27567bd46ccd93d18d53cef879e34f0951e37506b5e31a93e8784

find this code:

```
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        echo "\n\n";
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
    exit(Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);
}
```

and change to:

```
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
while ($e) {
    if ($e->getFile()) {
        echo sprintf("\nThere is an error in %s", $e->getFile());
        if ($e->getLine()) {
            echo sprintf(" at line: %d", $e->getLine());
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    echo "\n\n";
    $e = $e->getPrevious();
}
exit(Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please install this module **GetFinancing** in this link

https://github.com/WeGetFinancing/getfinancing-magento2

otherwise,

remove **GetFinancing** module from **composer.json** and **composer.lock** file

and then after run the command

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento static:content:deploy**

**php bin/magento cache/flush**

Comment: Thanks, I'm not looking for a specific solution to this error trace, but in general how to stop Magento 2 from truncating error messages so I can see the exact file that is causing the error. This was just an example error trace showing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a typecast `(real)` in the codebase of `Getfinancing` vendor and check what files contain that string.

Another solution would be to go into `ClassLoader.php` file and `echo` or `var_dump` the `$file` variable in the `loadClass` function
The last file that you will see in your cli before the error would be the problematic file and the file containing the `(real)` typecast.

Don't forget to undo your changes once you are done.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for this. It is a lot more work to trace an error that way so I will wait to see if someone knows how to solve the original issue which is instead of path/path... (cutoff) the full path/path/path/path/file.php before awarding.